# How to read my php/txt file content which is stored in databases(in one of it's columns) and display it?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a search bar on my home page through which I am trying to show the contents of php/txt file present in info column of my database .

```
//this is from home page 
if($khoj!=""){
$query=mysql_query("SELECT * from company_data where website like '%".$khoj."%' ");
$n=mysql_num_rows($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
header("refresh:1;url=cbresult.php");
$_SESSION['website']=$website;
$_SESSION['info']=$row['info'];
}
//2.cbresult.php(other code)
<?php
session_start();
include 'database2.php';
echo $_SESSION['website']."<br>".$_SESSION['info'];//instead of $_SESSION['info'] ,what should be present?
?>
```

Comment: what is the error message? and whats your question?

Comment: I am encountering problem on how to display the contents of the file,since it is a file I can't just echo it.so my question is to how to read and display it.

Comment: Please describe what the data is that is stored inside the `info` column of your database table. "A file" does not say how it is stored. As base64? Plaintext? Binary data?

Comment: The data stored in the info column is a text file.My aim here is to display the content of that text file .

Comment: You really should think about upgrading to PHP 7. mysql_* functions have been removed from PHP and should not be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Showing the contents of a file from the info column.

```
$file = file_get_contents($row['info']); 
echo $file;
```

This needs to be the path+filename to file if its not in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you mean by php/txt, so...

1. If the file has PHP code in it that you want to be executed, you should `include` it like you did with that other database file.

   ```
   include($_SESSION['info']);
   ```
2. If it's just plain text, you can use `readfile`.

   ```
   readfile($_SESSION['info']);
   ```